# how to do auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I know this may be a stupid question to ask but I have really forgotten how to do it.
How do I auto increment a photo ID whenever a record is inserted into mySQL database ?
I would want it to start with 1 for the first record and then subsequently +1 for the next. Thanks

I have set my database column photoID to PK, NN and AI.

Comment: AI is autoincrement

Comment: ... and will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) for AUTO_INCREMENT has a nice, clear example. In brief, if your field has been defined as auto incrementing, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  photoID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  anotherField VARCHAR(50),
  ....
);
```

then when you do an `INSERT`, if you do not specify a value for photoID, the value will auto increment (if you explicitly specify a value of NULL or 0 in the values list, the value will also auto increment):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (anotherField) VALUES ('something');
```

A SELECT would result in `photoID` value of 1, `anotherField` value of something.

Comment: hi jcmeloni, i have 7 columns in total for my database but my insert statement has only 6 values.                             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `picture` VALUES ('$facebookID', '$name', '$phone', '$email', '$pic', '$caption')");                      How do i add the AI value to go in for my photoID column ?

Comment: @ypercube wow. that is totally not what I meant to say, and you're absolutely right. I'll edit to say what I meant. thanks.

Comment: You either use:  `INSERT INTO picture(facebookId, name, phone, ...) VALUES (...)` or: `INSERT INTO picture VALUES (NULL, ...)`

Comment: The `NULL` will be overriden by the AI attribute.

Comment: Hey ybercube, thanks for the help !! manage to did it. sorry for all the trouble to other guys too for me being such a noob. Thanks alot :D

Comment: @Peter If you specify 6 fieldnames but not the 7th (the auto incrementing one), then the incrementing will happen automatically.  If you specify all fieldnames or do not specify any fieldnames (as in your example) then you have to account for the photoID as NULL, where it would normally fall in the values list.

Answer (score 1):

Set the 'photoID' column on the database to 'autoincrement' using phpmyadmin. It is one of the options on it. It will automatically then do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE foto ( ID int auto_increment, UNIQUE(ID) );